# Create input field in Google Docs form allowing only images

Tags: google, google-drive, google-forms

I need to make a Google Doc form, in which the users need to upload an image. Is it possible to do so using Google Docs form? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 3):

No, that is not possible in the standard Google Spreadsheet forms.

If you're capable of a little programming, you could implement your very own form with the [Google Apps Script GUI builder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/gui_builder). The GUI builder has a file upload element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Form+](http://www.formpl.us/) for that!
When your users upload files, each entry goes to your Google Drive.

Answer (score 0):

This might work (might not be exacrtly what you want)but I was able to accomplish posting images to a google doc by users submitting a form on a google site using Serge insas's excellent code:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15474002/2718835